# How to get a cell's formula VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching like crazy and I'm sure it is WAY simpler than I think so please enlighten me!

I set a formula on some cells in a loop like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("AM" & i).Formula = "=ROUND(Y" & i & "/(M" & i & "+U" & i & "/12))"
```

And I'd like to copy the RESULT of this formula to another cell. I tried this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("AM" & i).Value
```

But it's not working. I always wondered how to get the result (value) of this formula and not copy the entire formula.

Any idea or answer? Thanks so much.

Comment: It seems like it should work, have you made sure that it actually calculated it after placing the formula.  Also, the two formulas would be circular, so that may be the problem.

Comment: @Tom, You don't actually need to loop, to place the formula over a range of cells.  It can be done in one line.

Comment: Agree with both the comments above. The copy/paste answer you selected is really a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the result as a value. Suppose I have cells A1 and A2 and I want to get the `MAX` value in A3 and then copy the result to A4:

```
    A
1   10
2   20
3   20 <- as formula '=MAX(A1:A2)'
4   20 <- as value not formula

Sub AddMax()
    Range("A3").Formula = "=MAX(A1:A2)"
End Sub

Sub CopyResult()
    Range("A3").Copy
    Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) If you do ever use Copy in VBA then you should add a  `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to remove the copy selection around A3. (2) The example above could be done with one line `[a4].Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max([a1], [a2])` avoiding a copy

Comment: @brettdj - Thanks - good comments. I agree your point (2) and it wasn't clear to me why it wasn't working for the OP so I offered copy and paste as alternative.

Comment: Cheers Remant. My comments weren't intended to be critical ..they look bitier thatnI thought when I re-read them. Thanks for taking it as constructive in my intended manner

Comment: @brettdj - No problem. I welcome the advice and I am always humbled on this site about how much I don't know so I try to keep an open mind.